# Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

quiero hacer un auto scroll al final del `div` per ome sale este error, que no tengo idea, he pensado hacerlo con `useRef` pero no me deja.

o hay otra forma de hacer que el scroll se valla hacia el final?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
const Messages=()=>{
  
  let reff = useRef(null);
  const initdata = () => {}
  useEffect(() => {
    initdata({ page: 1, limit: 10 });
    if (reff?.current != null) {
      reff?.current?.scrollTop = reff?.current?.scrollHeight;
    }
  }, [sala, reff]);

  return <Box
        width='100%'
        overflow='auto'
        height='calc(100vh - 430px)'
        wrap='nowrap'
        ref={(ref) => (reff.current = ref)}>
        {messages.map((item) => (
          <Message key={v4()} message={item} />
        ))}
      </Box>
}
```

Comment: Faltan detalles, es decir,  ¿En que momento se dispara el autoscroll? No se ve un div, ¿Te refieres al Box? Describe el comportamiento del autoscroll, saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que te está dando es porque en esta línea:

```
reff?.current?.scrollTop = reff?.current?.scrollHeight;
```

Estás usando conditional chaining `?.` del lado izquierdo, cuando debería ser:

```
reff.current.scrollTop = reff?.current?.scrollHeight;
```